# Audio problems with my Vizio Tablet

Tags: audio, tablet

I have the 8 inch Vizio tablet Model VTAB1008.

The audio stops working out of no where. Even if I plug the headphones in, it doesn't work.

Usually when I completely turn it off, and then turn it back on again, the audio will work for a while, but then it will eventually stop working again.

The apps I use are just facebook, twitter, youtube, or instagram. No game apps or anything.

I've tried reformatting it, putting it back to default settings, didn't work. I've also tried SoundAbout, didn't work either.

The customer service guy told me to kill my apps before going to another app, saying sometimes one app doesn't give permission for another app to play sound, so I have done that using the Advanced Task killer, but no solution.

Anyone know what could be wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: One thing to note: The customer service guy should *not* be telling you to kill apps. http://www.howtogeek.com/127388/ Killing apps is not going to be a solution for this kind of problem and is almost never an actual solution to a problem in Android.